# Adding a row in a gridview from a Dictionary<Key,Value>

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I have a **LinkButton** on my Page1.aspx with the fields
Attached below is the image of page1.aspx. And a gridview in Page2.aspx.. When i click onto the linkbutton , the page redirects to Page2.aspx and fill the gridview with the required fields..

[image: **Page1.aspx with the Fields and a LinkButton**]

where the Required Fields are

**Image,
Name = Black Cap,
Title = Topi,
Price = 1200**

The Code of Page1.aspx:

```
 protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> OrderDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (e.CommandName == "orderClick")
    {
        string value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        string id = this.ListView1.DataKeys[e.Item.DataItemIndex].Value.ToString();
        OrderDict.Add(id, value);
        Session["Order"] = OrderDict;
        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
        Response.Write(OrderDict);
    }
}
```

The Code of Page2.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["Order"];
    //Regex reg = new Regex(@"\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)");
    if (Dictionary != null)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Dictionary;
        //Dictionary = reg.Matches(Dictionary.ToString()).Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value
        //    , x => x.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
        //string slit = Dictionary.s
        this.GridView1.DataBind();
        //this.GridView1.DataSource = Dictionary;
        Response.Write(Dictionary.Values.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I see code that binds to a dictionary. You should bind to the Keys property of the dictionary.

```
// Change your original line in Page_Load to this... The variable name conflicts with the class name
Dictionary<string, string> orderDictionary = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["Order"];

// Bind like this:
GridView1.DataSource = orderDictionary.Keys;
```

See [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue).Keys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx)

Have you considered creating a class that represents the list of items you're storing in the Session? For example:

```
public class SelectedOrder
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

// Then in your ListView ItemCommand in Page1.aspx
var orders = ((List<SelectedOrder>)Session["Order"]) ?? new List<SelectedOrder>();
orders.Add(new SelectedOrder() { ID = id, Value = value });
Session["Order"] = orders;

// And in Page2
List<SelectedOrder> orders = (List<SelectedOrder>)Session["Order"];
if (null != orders) {
    GridView1.DataSource = orders;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    // Rest of code follows...
}
```

I think this will be an easier approach to deal with in your code.